# Matplotlib Different Scaled Y-Axes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with the data below.

```
ex_dict = {'revenue': [613663,  1693667,  2145183,  2045065,  2036406,  
1708862,  1068232,  1196899,  2185852,  2165778,  2144738,  2030337,  
1784067],
'abs_percent_diff': [0.22279211315310588,  0.13248909660765254,  
0.12044821447874667,  0.09438674840975962,  0.1193588387687364,  
0.062100921139322744,  0.05875297161175445,  0.06240362963749895,  
0.05085338590212515,  0.034877614941165744,  0.012263947005671703,  
0.029227374323993634,  0.023411816504907524],
'ds': [dt.date(2017,1,1),  dt.date(2017,1,2),  dt.date(2017,1,3),  
dt.date(2017,1,4),  dt.date(2017,1,5),  dt.date(2017,1,6),  
dt.date(2017,1,7),  dt.date(2017,1,8),  dt.date(2017,1,9),  
dt.date(2017,1,10),  dt.date(2017,1,11),  dt.date(2017,1,12),  
dt.date(2017,1,13)], 
'yhat_normal': [501853.9074623253,  1952329.3521464923,  1914575.7673396615,  
1868685.8215084015,  1819261.1068672044,  1608945.031482406,  
1008953.0123101478,  1126595.36037955,  2302965.598289115,  
2244044.9351591542,  2171367.536396199,  2091465.0313570146,  
1826836.562382966]}

df_vis=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ex_dict)
```

I want to graph `yhat_normal` and `revenue` on the same y-axis and `abs_percent_diff` on a y-axis with a different scale.

```
df_vis = df_vis.set_index('ds')
df_vis[['rev', 'yhat_normal']].plot(figsize=(20, 12))
```

I can easily graph `rev` and `yhat_normal` with the code above, but I am struggling to get `abs_percent_diff` on a different y-axis scale. I tried converting my columns to numpy arrays and doing this, but it looks terrible.

```
npdate = df_vis.as_matrix(columns= ['ds'])
nppredictions = df_vis.as_matrix(columns= ['yhat_normal'])
npactuals = df_vis.as_matrix(columns= ['rev'])
npmape = df_vis.as_matrix(columns=['abs_percent_diff'])

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
fig.set_size_inches(20,10)
ax1.plot_date(npdate, nppredictions, ls= '-', color= 'b')
ax1.plot_date(npdate, npactuals, ls='-', color='g')
ax2.plot_date(npdate, npmape, 'r-')

ax1.set_xlabel('X data')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y1 data', color='g')
ax2.set_ylabel('Y2 data', color='b')

plt.show()
```

This is what I want. Where the red line is the abs_percent_diff. Obviously, I drew the line by hand so it is not accurate. [image]

Comment: Hi,  I edited you question but still your example is not replicable as `npdate`, `nppredictions`, `npactuals` and `npmape` are missing. Anyway have you checked this [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/two_scales.html)?

Comment: Ok, I added some code. Yes, I have checked the documentation.

Comment: Could you format the code such that it can be copied and run? Also, showing an image of the output and clearly stating what is wrong with it could motivate people to answer here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yeah good idea.  I formatted the code so you can easily load it into a dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got the problem correclty, but it seems you simply want to draw one of the dataframe columns at the bottom of the plot area.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ex_dict = {'revenue': [613663,  1693667,  2145183,  2045065,  2036406,  
1708862,  1068232,  1196899,  2185852,  2165778,  2144738,  2030337,  
1784067],
'abs_percent_diff': [0.22279211315310588,  0.13248909660765254,  
0.12044821447874667,  0.09438674840975962,  0.1193588387687364,  
0.062100921139322744,  0.05875297161175445,  0.06240362963749895,  
0.05085338590212515,  0.034877614941165744,  0.012263947005671703,  
0.029227374323993634,  0.023411816504907524],
'ds': [dt.date(2017,1,1),  dt.date(2017,1,2),  dt.date(2017,1,3),  
dt.date(2017,1,4),  dt.date(2017,1,5),  dt.date(2017,1,6),  
dt.date(2017,1,7),  dt.date(2017,1,8),  dt.date(2017,1,9),  
dt.date(2017,1,10),  dt.date(2017,1,11),  dt.date(2017,1,12),  
dt.date(2017,1,13)], 
'yhat_normal': [501853.9074623253,  1952329.3521464923,  1914575.7673396615,  
1868685.8215084015,  1819261.1068672044,  1608945.031482406,  
1008953.0123101478,  1126595.36037955,  2302965.598289115,  
2244044.9351591542,  2171367.536396199,  2091465.0313570146,  
1826836.562382966]}

df_vis=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ex_dict)

df_vis = df_vis.set_index('ds')
ax = df_vis[['revenue','yhat_normal']].plot(figsize=(13, 8))
ax2 = df_vis['abs_percent_diff'].plot(secondary_y=True, ax=ax)
ax2.set_ylim(0,1)


plt.show()
```

[image]